# Changing the source topic name using a CREATE STREAM query in ksqldb headless deployment mode

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a topic whose name contains dots, it was created with the Debezium connector, it's there and I can't do much about it.

With ksqldb I must create a materialized stream view out of it, but topic names with dots are not allowed in the SELECT clause.

So I must first declare the original topic with a new name, right?

```
CREATE STREAM datachanges_my_event WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='datachanges.my.event', <...>);
```

and then create the materialized stream view

```
CREATE STREAM my_filtered_event AS SELECT <expr> FROM datachanges_my_event WHERE <condition> EMIT CHANGES;
```

It's all good, but now I must try my best to do this as part of a deployment in headless mode; however, the first ksql query is not persistent and does not make sense in headless mode. On the other side, I cannot run the first query in interactive mode and the the second one as part of a headless deployment mode.

So, please, how can change the name of a source topic within a query run as part of a ksqldb headless deployment?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like `CREATE` commands are allowed in headless mode: https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/operate-and-deploy/how-it-works/#supported-operations-in-headless-and-interactive-modes

Can you share which command(s) you ran in headless mode and any errors you got with it?

Comment: GeoJim, I have learned that one cannot run a CREATE STREAM query in headless mode, without having at least also an CREATE STREAM AS query to create a materialized stream view. Or at least, I think. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cannot run a CREATE STREAM query in headless mode, without having at least also an CREATE STREAM AS query to create a materialized stream view.